# Granting root privileges to another user on my Cent OS install?

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, ftp, sftp

I have disabled root on my webserver account for security purposes, and have granted root privileges to another user in order to use that user instead of having to keep re-enabling root just to check error logs.

Filezilla still gives me a PERMISSION DENIED when using SFTP, but not completely. I can access SOME extra stuff, but definitely not the root/home directory where I need.

Any ideas? Did I do something wrong when adding user? Is there a way to test this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should include how exactly you "granted root privileges" and how you created the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you changed it, the root home directory directory /root is owned by root and can be accessed by users in the root group. Some of the access restrictions may simply be explained by missing group membership for your new user.

To find out what groups a user belongs to:

```
groups username
```

To add an existing user to a group:

```
usermod username -A groupname
```

To create a new user with group membership:

```
useradd -G groupname1,groupname2 username
```

I would not recommend adding a user to the root group though. I would create something like an "admin" group and control access that way. Also, another good way to limit root access is using [sudo](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo)

Comment: Sudo is great, but not for FTP usage, as there is nowhere to use sudo there.

I added my user the group 'wheel' which is supposed to have root like privileges, but for some reason, it does not. I need to leave root disable, and still have access to my sftp files.